# AutoComplete in WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Which interface in Windows Forms provides the following properties that support auto complete?

```
AutoCompleteCustomSource 
AutoCompleteSource 
AutoCompleteMode
```

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx) pretty much explains it in detail.

Comment: MSDN probably explains a lot of things in detail. If not MSDN, then other online QA site, if not then books and reference manuals, etc. People post questions because they can't find answers. I am looking for help. Do you take pleasure in voting down questions?

Comment: Those properties are not specified under any interface.  TextBox, ComboBox implement them directly.  If you are looking to implement your own control from scratch with AutoComplete, Manish's answer gives good links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement/drive the Form class.

refer below link which has complete implementation

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article225.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/AutoCompletion02012006113508AM/AutoCompletion.aspx